# How to apply friction on the car so that car slow down

Tags: unity, c#, physics

I am working on a driving game. I am able to move the car using arrow key.I am accelerating the car by applying a force in what ever direction that car is.But I need to apply friction to the car so that the car slow downs more quickly.How can I do it.Here is the code I am using for the movement

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) ) {
        rb.AddForce( transform.up * speedForce);
    }
```

after some search.I found that some used this line of code

```
rigidbody2D.drag=friction;
```

And I edited my script as below

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) ) {
        rb.AddForce( transform.up * speedForce);
        rb.drag=friction;
    }
```

Will this make any sense in applying friction.Can anybody please help me .

Comment: You only need to set the drag value once.  That being said, how would you expect someone to answer this simple question, with a Yes or No answer?    https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-drag.html

Comment: "How would you expect someone to answer this simple question, with a yes or no answer?" you know maybe you could answer it, and explain why its yes or no. Would be more helpful.

Comment: Also are you working with 2d, or 3d?

Comment: @Ryanwhite He is not asking a question, he is looking for confirmation.  I also explained to him everything there is to explain in a comment.

Comment: because now he fully understands why he only sets the drag value once. Good job!

Comment: @Ryanwhite : Iam working with 2D

Comment: Ok, now as youv been told you only apply the drag value here once. The reason why is because every time the up arrow is pressed, the code is run. simple terms, the code loops through and checks for the input, it then detects the input and runs the code with the drag value. Thus, the code only has to be wrote once because it will always be accessible.